# Dynamic datatype in generics java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming

I have a usecase where client is sending a List<Function>. Task is to iterate and execute this function and keep it in a TypedSafeMap.
pseudo client code:

```
Function<String, Integer> firstFn = x -> x.length();
Function<String, String> secondFn = x -> x.substring(0);

client.runTheseFunctions(Arrays.asList(firstFn, secondFn));
```

Inside `runtTheseFunctions` in the code, task is to execute these functions and keep it in a TypedSafeMap where the key is the datatype of the type of the result of the function and value is the return of functions.apply();

The code below

```
public static void runTheseFunctions(List<Function<Employee, ?>> lst, Employee o) {
           lst.stream().forEach( x -> {
             typedSafeMap.put(????, x.apply(o));  
        //The key is nothing but the datatype of the x.apply(o).
        //How do I add this in runtime here. Generics is all compile time safety.
           });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void runTheseFunctions(List<Function<Employee, ?>> lst, Employee o) {
    lst.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.apply(o).getClass(), f -> f.apply(o)));
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: You could move the `f.apply(o)` to  `stream.map(f -> f.apply(o))`, so that it doesn't need to be called twice in the `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your "runTheseFunctions" method as shown below:

```
    public static void runTheseFunctions(List<Function<Employee, ?>> lst, Employee o) {
        Map<Class<?>, Object> typedSafeMap = new HashMap<>();

        lst.stream().forEach(x -> {
            Object value = x.apply(o);
            typedSafeMap.put(value.getClass(), value);
        });

        System.out.println(typedSafeMap);
    }
```

Comment: Nice. we had same idea mate ;)

Comment: You could move the `x.apply(o)` method to `map` instead of `forEach` and then `collect` the results. `.map(f -> f.apply(o)).collect(Collectors.toMap(result -> result.getClass(), Function.identity()));`

Answer (score 1):

In case the List of Functions contains two or more Functions with the same outputtype (for instance: String getFirstName, String getLastName, toMap will fail. So an alternative is:

```
var map = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(
    f -> f.apply(e).getClass(), 
    mapping(f -> f.apply(e), toList())
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want to achieve, and you can use for your tests. I assumed an trivial implementation of `Employee` class, just to give you an idea:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Employee {
    String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int length() {
        return name.length();
    }

    public String substring(int index) {
        return name.substring(index);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e = new Employee("Marco");

        Function<Employee, Integer> firstFn = x -> x.length();
        Function<Employee, String> secondFn = x -> x.substring(0);

        runTheseFunctions(Arrays.asList(firstFn, secondFn), e);

    }

    public static void runTheseFunctions(List<Function<Employee, ?>> lst, Employee o) {

        Map<Class, Object> typedSafeMap = new HashMap<>();

        lst.stream().forEach(x -> {

            Object result = x.apply(o);

            typedSafeMap.put(x.apply(o).getClass(), x.apply(o));
            // The key is nothing but the datatype of the x.apply(o).
            // How do I add this in runtime here. Generics is all compile time safety.
        });

        typedSafeMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue()));
    }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
class java.lang.String - Marco
class java.lang.Integer - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing @Yonas answer:

```
private static Map<?, ? extends Object> runTheseFunctions(List<Function<String, ? extends Object>> list, String o) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(f -> f.apply(o))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(result -> result.getClass(), Function.identity()));
}
```

This will call the `f.apply(o)` only once.